# passing parameters between jsp pages and servlets

Tags: java, html, web-services, jsp, servlets

I am new to web services jsps and servlets and i have this very simple example just to understand how things work.

At first, i have this simple web service :

```
    package com.sav.calculator;

    import javax.jws.WebService;
    import javax.jws.WebMethod;
    import javax.jws.WebParam;

    @WebService(serviceName = "CalculatorWS")
    public class CalculatorWS {

        @WebMethod(operationName = "add")
        public int add(@WebParam(name = "i") int i, @WebParam(name = "j") int j) {
            int k = i + j;
            return k;
        }

    }
```

Then i use this web service in my client application. Im trying to work the right way so i send data from a jsp to servlet, do the calculations in the servlet and send the data in another jsp for the presentation.. but the question is why im not getting it right?

here is the first jsp(just an html form):

```
    <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        </head>
        <body>

            <form method="POST" action="ClientServlet">
                <input type="text" name="j"/>
                <input type="text" name="i"/>
                <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
            </form>

        </body>
    </html>
```

here is the servlet where i use my add webmethod:

```
package com.sav.calculator.client;

import com.sav.calculator.CalculatorWS_Service;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.xml.ws.WebServiceRef;

@WebServlet(name = "ClientServlet", urlPatterns = {"/ClientServlet"})
public class ClientServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @WebServiceRef(wsdlLocation = "WEB-INF/wsdl/localhost_8080/CalculatorWSApplication/CalculatorWS.wsdl")
    private CalculatorWS_Service service;

    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
        doPost(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);

        int i = (int) request.getAttribute("i");
        int j = (int) request.getAttribute("j");

        int k = add(i, j);
        request.setAttribute("k",k);

        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("newjsp2.jsp");
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }

    private int add(int i, int j) {
        com.sav.calculator.CalculatorWS port = service.getCalculatorWSPort();
        return port.add(i, j);
    }

}
```

And the newjsp2 is just a hello world page, im just trying to get there first but what i get is :
[that.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bCIk8.png)

Answer (score 0):

After starting web-service server, in web browser type address:

```
 http://localhost:8080/CalculatorWSApplication/CalculatorWS.wsdl
```

if this address contains an wsdl (xml format) then use it as your *wsdlLocation*.

Try also some tool, like [SoapUI, or some other](https://dzone.com/articles/12-great-web-service-testing-tools).

Answer (score 0):

**From Servlet to JSP**

You could set values into the response object before forwarding request to jsp. Or you can put your values into a session bean and access it in the jsp.

**From JSP to Servlet**

You need to submit a form and pass parameter as an input. **An example** ...

```
<form method="Post" action="path/to/servlet">
    <input type="text" name="x" />
    <input type="password" name="xx" />
    <input type="hidden" name="xxx" value="zzz" />
    <input type='submit' />
</form>
```